# Copying Android Studio project, making edits to copy, and building to phone uploads the old project to my phone

Tags: android, refactoring, android-studio

I am making an app following a book tutorial and at the end of each chapter there are "challenges" to add onto the app and the book suggests making a copy of the project and working on the challenges on the copy so you dont accidentally mess up the original.

I right clicked my project in the project explorer in android studio and went to Refactor ->Copy and typed in a new name. Then i opened the new version with a different name and made changes to the files (including adding a button and new actions when the button is pressed).

But when i run it and select my phone it my phone opens up the old project without the changes.

What is going on? How do i make a copy of a project and make changes so i can upload it to my phone as a new and separate app?

Comment: Are you sure you run the new project?

Comment: In android studio you only have the option to run the project that is opened i believe. Not like eclipse where you can choose from many in your workspace.

Comment: you can try to edit the app_name in string.xml,if nothing changed,try to uninstall the origin app and run the project again.

Comment: I've tried both, neither works. Running the app still uploads the old version that i don't even have open in android studio.